# Automated tools to downgrade php 5.5 code to php 5.3 code?

Tags: php, automation

I have a large number of source files where I have made use of various newer PHP features - in particular binary numbers, short array syntax, function array dereferencing, and finally blocks.

With the exception of the latter it seems to me that these would be fairly trivial to write a tool to automatically downgrade (assuming no insanity like usage of eval) the code and in fact if I'm unable to find any then I think I will basically have to.

Still, the reason that I have ended up in this position is because I am new to the language in the first place so just because I couldn't find anything (other than php -l) doesn't mean that such a tool doesn't exist. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: I need to ask the obvious question, why do you need to downgrade? PHP 5.3 will be unsupported mid-2014. Seems like there will be more effort to downgrade, and ending up using an unsupported version vs upgrading the PHP version.

Comment: Because it has to run on an ancient environment - in fact a version of Zend which is old enough as to be unsupported aiui . This is beyond my control sadly.

Comment: There are no mature projects doing this. Just some small experiments like https://github.com/igorw/galapagos or https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Backporter, but nothing that is actually in a usable state ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've just published a tool to convert PHP 5.4+ code into PHP 5.3 compatible: https://github.com/endel/php-code-downgrade

It's mainly based upon `igorw/galapagos` and `nikic/PHP-Parser` projects. So don't thank me, thank them! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I work on an open-source tool that handles instant upgrades but also **instant downgrades**.

**From PHP 8.0 to PHP 5.4** - it's called Rector: http://github.com/rectorphp/rector

We eat our own dog food... :) Rector itself is developed in PHP 7.3 and code downgraded to PHP 7.1:

- root [composer.json](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/e1c87b5900c7d68e87519ea4a621e2259b9de26d/composer.json#L28) with PHP 7.3+
- release [composer.json](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-prefixed/blob/b47b7686adff8ed4854fa514ec8ca07b2c4e25e9/composer.json#L9) with PHP 7.1+